# Appalling write speed using NFS

Tags: nfs

I've set up a NFS share on my Raspberry by installing @nfs-kernel-server@ and configuring the following export:

```
/media/hdd 192.168.1.0/24(rw,async)
```

I've mounted the share on a Ubuntu client using

```
192.168.1.51:/media/hdd /media/myuser/hdd nfs hard,intr,rsize=X,wsize=Y,proto=Z
```

and tried with several values for X, Y and Z. However, no matter what values I use, copying a large (~8GB) file to the share will start at ~45MB/s for the first ~800MB and suddenly drop to an appalling ~800KB/s and sometimes even freeze. What am I doing wrong? I am using Xbian 1.0 Beta 1.1.

Comment: could you please install samba and see if there's any difference?

Comment: What are your current values for X, Y and Z?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with regular dekstop-clients and servers. Turned out NFS gave false reading regarding speed, since it cached a lot and basically said it was done with lots of MB/GB, while it was still copying in the background. This was only notable when copying large files, since the internal cache was exhausted.

First of all, use this command to test the performance:

```
dd bs=1M count=512 if=/dev/zero of=/media/myuser/hdd/test conv=fdatasync
```

Second, try using some other protocol. [sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) or just scp is a good indicator of performance-speed.

I also noticed that the default values for rsize,wsize where good engough. Thats not where to start looking.